# Check whether password is correct or not using codeigniter

Tags: php, html, database, codeigniter

I want to validate the password entered correct or not. I use following code,

Controller

```
$pWord = $_POST['pword'];
 if($this->model_users->check($uName) == $pWord) {
      echo 'Loggedin!';
 } else {
      echo 'Incorrect password!';
 }
```

Model

```
function check($username) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT password FROM user WHERE user_name= '$username'");
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
}
```

View

```
<form action="/test/index.php/login/valid" method="POST">
            Username :<input name="uname" type="text"> <br><br>
            Password :<input name="pword" type="password"> <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Enter">
</form>
```

but i couldn't get "Loggedin!" when i entered correct password that exist in database.

Comment: This code implies that you're storing plain text passwords, which is by all accounts a big no-no.

Comment: Have you store plain password into database??

Comment: yes I stored plain password in database

Comment: @user3002114 Would suggest fixing that particular issue first really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return the password,not result array. Use following code,

```
function check($username) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT password FROM user WHERE user_name= '$username'");
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->row()->password;
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
}
```